# How to subtract or add different set amounts across multiple cells by referencing another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So basically im trying to add or subtract various set amounts from a stock list from entering one number ie 1 pallet = 5 apples 10 bananas 6 oranges and 2 pears, so when i enter 1 pallet it automatically adds or subtracts the set amount of "apples, bananas" from the main stock list or in multiples if i select 2 or 3 pallets etc.

ive no idea where to start with this so any ideas??

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is too broad. At least you should add a manual input and expected output so we can help with the formulas. Right now this is a shot in the darkness. Maybe you could do  do like a tabular table with each column being the amount of each fruit and then depending on how many pallets you type in a different cell it will read those columns and multiply. Anyways, as I said, it would be helpful an expected output

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply i think im over complicating what im trying to achieve, i want to be able to add/sub a pallet, by entering 1 pallet excel then knows that 1 pallet consists of 10 apples 3 bananas and 7 pears and then adjusts the stock +/- for the apples/bananas/pears accordingly on the main stock list

Answer (score 0):

Excel is writing your function as you go along by just start of entering = in a cell. Then select the cell containing your stock, and use + or - between each step. Press Enter to se the result ;-)
[image]
Normally you will se the formula is using the cell reference like(G2) =F2-(E$8*B2)+(E$9*B2). This means you can drag it and the reference follows in sequence.

Comment: im trying to get it to automatically add/subtract from the main stock list so by me adding/subtracting 1 pallet or multiple pallets it then knows that one pallet consists of 10 apples 5 bananas or 2 pallets would be 20 apples 10 bananas etc so i dont have to manually add or subtract about 15 different items (apples, bananas, etc) each with different quantity instead i can just add/sub a pallet  and it knows how much apples/bananas/etc to change on the stock list.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, the question is unclear but this is just and example of how you could store your data and then, depending on how many pallets you choose, calculate subtotals and grandtotals for each fruit:

[image]

This example allows you to manage different types of pallets (let's say pallet A can hold only 1 apple, but pallet C can hold 9 apples) and calculate everything on the right side. You just input what type of pallet you want and how many and everything will be calculated.

The left side is source data so everything is manual input. The right side needs manual input only in columns I (Pallet type) and J (quantity of pallets). Rest of columns are formulas.

Cell K2 got this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($I2,$A$2:$E$4,MATCH(K$1,$A$1:$E$1,0);FALSE)*$J2
```

Drag to right this formula untill cell N2 and then drag down (in my example is just 2 rows).

Formula in cell O2 is `=SUM(J2:N2)` just drag down too.

Finally, the grand totals row is just another summatory of everything above. Cell J6 is `=SUM(J2:J3)` and drag to right untill O6.

Anyways, probably there are a lot of ways doing this.